# vue2js - how to propagate selected index with chosen select value in a direcitve

Tags: vuejs2, jquery-chosen, vue-directives

Please look at the code below. The first select box is created with [chosen js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). When changed it should propagate its changed value to the model to which its bound (`cityid`). The second normal select box is working fine and its value is propagated.

```js
Vue.directive('chosen', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {

    Vue.nextTick(function() {

      $(el).chosen({
        width:'100%'
      }).change(function(){

        alert($(el).val());
        vnode.context.$emit('input', $(el).val());
        
      });
    });

  },
  update: function(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {

  }
});


new Vue({
  el : '#app',
  data:{
    cityid : 3,
    cities : [
      {id:1, value:'London'},
      {id:2, value:'Newyork'},
      {id:3, value:'Delhi'}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" >  
  
<div id="app">
    selected city id # {{ cityid }}
    <hr>
    <select v-chosen v-model="cityid">
      <option v-for="option in cities" :value="option.id" >{{option.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <select  v-model="cityid">
      <option v-for="option in cities" :value="option.id" >{{option.value}}</option>
    </select>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are emitting in your directive, you are emitting the event from the root node (the `context`). You need to emit the event from the node itself. You don't have access to the $emit event, but you can examine the handlers that have been attached to the node. In this case, `v-model` is applying a `change` handler. As such, if you write your directive like this, your code should work.

```
Vue.directive('chosen', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
    Vue.nextTick(function() {
      $(el).chosen({
        width:'100%'
      }).change(function(e){
        vnode.data.on.change(e, $(el).val())
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LywzLW?editors=1010).